# Get a reference for the current frame

Tags: frames, focus

`frame-list` returns a list of references for live Emacs frames.  How does one get a reference for the *current* Emacs frame?  I have been unable to find an appropriate function.  Current could be either **(1)** the Emacs frame that has focus (one or zero references) or **(2)** the Emacs frame that last had focus.

I'm presently looking to use **(1)** under w32, but for didactic purposes I'm interested in both and whether there are any caveats for focus tracking in Emacs.

Comment: How about `selected-frame`?

Comment: Yes; that's the synonym I was looking for!  My apropos-command searches were coming up empty :-\

Comment: Use `M-x apropos`, not `apropos-command` (frame functions are generally not commands).

Comment: Interesting.  That explains why I usually don't get useful information from `C-h a` (`apropos-command`).  I primarily rely on `describe-function` and `describe-variable` narrowed with helm.  Now that I know of `apropos` I'm going to bind that to `C-h a`!  Thanks for pointing that out, @Drew.

Comment: @ebpa: If you're using Helm, you may also be interested in `helm-apropos`, which jams sources for all of the different symbol types (variable, function, etc.) into one Helm command.  That's what I use on `C-h a`.

Comment: Thanks for the `apropos` vs `apropos-command` tip. I was suffering exactly the same problem, searching for `(selected-frame)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `selected-frame` and `selected-window` to get the current frame and window. Also see the `focus-in-hook` an `focus-out-hook` hooks (new in Emacs 24.4) if you want to take some action when a frame gains or loses focus.

Comment: I gather that since you mention `focus-in-hook` there isn't any tracking of frame focus?  The command description for `select-frame` has a "NORECORD" parameter which only mentions recently selected windows and buffers which supports that.

Comment: The buffer list order is updated when you switch buffers. I believe `select-frame` also calls `select-window`, which changes the current buffer. NORECORD is used to temporarily switch to another frame/window/buffer without changing the buffer list order. I don't think a separate ordered history is maintained for frames or windows. See also `get-mru-window`, which finds the most recently selected window by looking at the `window-use-time`, rather than by querying some ordered list.

Comment: See also `select-frame-set-input-focus`. The `selected-frame` does not necessarily have the input focus.